# When I try to write to a file using python script in a batch file and then run it. It doesn't write to the file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have tried writing some content to a file by running a python code in a batch file.I have used the following as the batch command.

python C:\Python27\filtercsv.py

When I tried running the program in IDLE or in the command prompt, it was writing to the file. But, when I tried the same using the batch file, it wasn't writing.

I have included python in the PATH environment variable. So, I guess I don't need to specify the .exe file's location.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you write the file to an absolute path?

If not you might want to either change the current directory in the batch file before running the script:

```
pushd C:\Python27
python filtercsv.py
popd
```

or include a path in the file name you're writing to.

This is because of if you write to a file just by name it will show up in the current working directory, which is not necessarily where the script is located.

(However, you should probably not save your scripts in your Python installation directory, nor write files there because you don't usually have write access there.)